# Is it possible to reduce HTTP request headers size?

Tags: http-headers, azure-web-app-service, mtu

We currently have issue where our application has to go through a tunnel where MTU is set to a low value to reach out client API gateway. To illustrate it will be "Client --> App in Azure --> Tunnel with low MTU --> API gateway.

We have confirmed with Microsoft that we can't change the MTU value in Azure because we are using App Service on Azure, and it is not possible to increase the MTU value of the tunnel. The body of our requests are relatively small. Thus, is there a way we can compress the request headers?

P.S. Rebuilding the application on VM is not an option due to time constraints.

P.S.S. We tried putting a forward proxy in front of the App service but we can't redirect the traffic from App service to the proxy

Answer (score 0):

I'm not certain this will completely address your issue but you might be able to alter your projects web.config outlined here: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/removing-standard-server-headers-on-windows-azure-web-sites/

Hopefully that helps. If it doesn't, have you considered deploying your application to a VM? That would give complete control over IIS configurations.